# helperText error in the code added validation also, but it's not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

I tried to fix the issue in various methods and ways, but it's not fixing. I am not able to know why it's getting an error, and I don't understand the exact issue in the code.

The error is:

> helperText not defined for select property below is the code & validation

[image]

```
    import React,{useState} from "react";
    import { connect } from "react-redux";
    import { Form, withFormik } from "formik";
    import {
      Box,
      Typography,
      FormLabel,
      Button,
      Grid,
      FormHelperText,
      Divider,
      InputLabel,
      MenuItem,
      FormControl,
      Select,
    } from "@material-ui/core";
    import { CurrencyTxtField } from "components/core";
    import { orders as validationSchema } from "utilities/validationSchemas";

    const Orders = ({
      errors,
      handleChange,
      handleBlur,
      touched,
      isSubmitting,
      isValid,
      dirty,
      values,
    }) => {
      const [shipping, setShipping] = useState("");
      const handleShipping = (event) => {
        setShipping(event.target.value);
      };

      return (
        <Form>
          <FormLabel color="secondary" component="legend">
            <Typography variant="h4" component="h5">
              Order Minimum
            </Typography>
          </FormLabel>
          <Box pt={2}>
            <Grid container spacing={1}>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <InputLabel>Wholesale Price</InputLabel>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <FormHelperText>
                  Your's Store Purshase minimum on a customer order.
                </FormHelperText>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={4}>
                <CurrencyTxtField
                  id="order"
                  name="order"
                  label=""
                  variant="outlined"
                  currencySymbol="$"
                  outputFormat="number"
                  digitGroupSeparator=""
                  textAlign="left"
                  selectOnFocus="true"
                  value={values.order}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  autoFocus={true}
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  error={!!errors.order}
                  helperText={errors.order ? errors.order : ""}
                />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Box pt={2}>
              <Button
                disabled={isSubmitting || !dirty || !isValid}
                size="medium"
                variant="contained"
                color="secondary"
                fullWidth={false}
                type="submit"
              >
                Save Changes
              </Button>
            </Box>
          </Box>

          <Box pt={3} pb={4}>
            <Divider light />
          </Box>

          <FormLabel color="secondary" component="legend">
            <Typography variant="h4" component="h4">
              Reorder Minimum
            </Typography>
          </FormLabel>
          <Box pt={2}>
            <Grid container spacing={1}>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <InputLabel>Minimum Reorder Amount(optional)</InputLabel>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <FormHelperText>
                  Your's Store Purshase minimum on any reorders.
                </FormHelperText>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={4}>
                <CurrencyTxtField
                  id="reOrder"
                  name="reOrder"
                  label=""
                  variant="outlined"
                  currencySymbol="$"
                  outputFormat="number"
                  digitGroupSeparator=""
                  textAlign="left"
                  selectOnFocus="true"
                  value={values.reOrder}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  autoFocus={true}
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  error={!!errors.reOrder  && touched.reOrder}
                  helperText={errors.reOrder ? errors.reOrder : ""}
                />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Box pt={2}>
              <Button
                disabled={isSubmitting || !dirty || !isValid}
                size="medium"
                variant="contained"
                color="secondary"
                fullWidth={false}
                type="submit"
              >
                Save Changes
              </Button>
            </Box>
          </Box>

          <Box pt={3} pb={4}>
            <Divider light />
          </Box>


          <FormLabel color="secondary" component="legend">
            <Typography variant="h4" component="h4">
             Ship Lead Time
            </Typography>
          </FormLabel>
          <Box pt={2}>
            <Grid container spacing={1}>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <FormHelperText>
                  The standard amount of time between order acceptance and when the
                  order is shipped.
                </FormHelperText>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={8}>
                <FormControl
                variant="outlined"
                  style={{ width: "200px" }}
                >
                  <Select
                    id="shippingTime"
                    name= "shippingTime"
                    label=""
                    variant="outlined"
                    value={shipping}
                    onChange={handleShipping}
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    error={!!errors.shippingTime}
                    helperText={errors.shippingTime ? errors.shippingTime : ""}
                  >
                    <MenuItem value={0}>
                      <em>None</em>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value={1}>1-3 Days</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value={2}>4-7 Days</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value={3}>7-14 Days</MenuItem>
                  </Select>
                </FormControl>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>

            <Box pt={2}>
              <Button
                disabled={isSubmitting || !dirty || !isValid}
                size="medium"
                variant="contained"
                color="secondary"
                fullWidth={false}
                type="submit"
              >
                Save Changes
              </Button>
              </Box>

          </Box>

        </Form>
      );
    };

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({});

    const mapActionsToProps = {};

    const formikOptions = {
      enableReinitialize: true,
      mapPropsToValues: (props) => ({
        order: "",
        reOrder: "",
      }),
      validationSchema,
      validateOnChange: true,
      handleSubmit: () => {},
    };

    export default connect(
      mapStateToProps,
      mapActionsToProps,
    )(withFormik(formikOptions)(Orders));

        export const orders = Yup.object().shape({
      order: Yup.number().required("Minimum order price is required."),
      reorder: Yup.number().required("Minimum reorder price is required."),
      shippingTime:Yup.string().required("Standard shipping-time is required"),
    });
```

CurrencyTXT

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Box, InputLabel, FormHelperText } from "@material-ui/core";
import CurrencyTextField from "@unicef/material-ui-currency-textfield";

const CurrencyTxtField = ({
    defaultValue,
    disabled,
    error,
    helperText,
    id,
    label,
    labelHidden,
    name,
  onChange,
  onBlur,
    persistHelperText,
    required,
  value,
  digitGroupSeparator,
  variant,
  currencySymbol,
  outputFormat,
  textAlign,
}) => {
  return (
    <Box pt={1.5}>
      {labelHidden
        ? <Box component="label" display="none">{label}</Box>
        : <InputLabel htmlFor={id} required={required} disabled={disabled}>{label}</InputLabel>
      }
      <CurrencyTextField
        label=""
        variant={variant}
        value={value}
        currencySymbol={currencySymbol}
        outputFormat={outputFormat}
        digitGroupSeparator={digitGroupSeparator}
        textAlign={textAlign}
        onChange={onChange}
        onBlur={onBlur}
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
        disabled={disabled}
        required={required}
        name={name}
        id={id}
        error={error}
      />
      <FormHelperText error={error} disabled={disabled}>{(error || persistHelperText) && helperText}</FormHelperText>
    </Box>
    );
  };

CurrencyTxtField.defaultProps = {
    disabled: false,
    error: false,
    labelHidden: false,
    type: "text",
    persistHelperText: false,
    currencySymbol: "$",
    outputFormat: "number",
    digitGroupSeparator: "",
    variant: "outlined",
  };

  CurrencyTxtField.propTypes = {
    autoFocus: PropTypes.bool,
    inputComponent: PropTypes.func,
    defaultValue: PropTypes.node,
    disabled: PropTypes.bool,
    error: PropTypes.bool,
    helperText: PropTypes.string,
    id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    labelHidden: PropTypes.bool,
    name: PropTypes.string,
    onBlur: PropTypes.func,
    onChange: PropTypes.func,
    persistHelperText: PropTypes.bool,
    required: PropTypes.bool,
    type: PropTypes.string,
    value: PropTypes.node,
  };

  export default CurrencyTxtField;
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: And please fix the [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) of your question

Comment: can you share your `CurrencyTxtField` , are you sure you got a `helperText` props in it ?

Comment: I had added it plz check it